# How to use select MIN() in SQL when one field can not be grouped?

Tags: sql, min

I am quite new to SQL so please be gentle. I have tried search for an answer but can not find anything.

I have the following data in a table

```
Code    Area        Department          Level    Name
HWNET   Highways    Network Services    2        Bob Jones
HWNET   Highways    Network Services    1        Jim Smith
HWTRA   Highways    Traffic Services    2        Andy Johnson
HWTRA   Highways    Traffic Services    1        David Turner
```

I want to select all the columns from the table but only for the minimum value for each level. My problem is that I need to know the Name but this is stopping me from using the group by function

If I use this it brings back every row in the table

```
SELECT Code, Area, Department,MIN(Level) Level , Name
FROM TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY Code, Area,Department, Name
```

This brings back the correct rows but does not contain the Name.

```
SELECT Code, Area, Department,MIN(Level) Level
FROM TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY Code, Area,Department
```

Is there a way for me bring back this set of results?

```
Code    Area        Department          Level    Name
HWNET   Highways    Network Services    1        Jim Smith
HWTRA   Highways    Traffic Services    1        David Turner
```

Thanks is advance

Comment: Thanks you very much for taking the time to assist. I tried the solution for juergen d above and that worked. But once again thank you for taking the time to help.

Answer (score 3):

```
select t.* 
from TABLE_NAME t
inner join
(
  SELECT Code, Area, Department,MIN(Level) mLevel
  FROM TABLE_NAME
  GROUP BY Code, Area,Department
) x on x.Code = t.code 
    and x.Area = t.area 
    and x.Department = t.Department 
    and x.mLevel = t.level
```

Comment: That you very much juergen d. Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Usually I do it in this ways:

```
select *
  from TABLE_NAME
 where (Department, 
        Level) in (select Department,
                          min(Level)
                     from TABLE_NAME
                 group by Department)
```

Here a [demo in SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/762cd/1).

Based on your data I used only Department and Level, but if you need to use also Code and Area to identify the right rows just ass them in the WHERE clause and in the SELECT of the subquery.

```
select *
  from TABLE_NAME
 where (Code,
        Area
        Department, 
        Level) in (select Code,
                          Area,
                          Department,
                          min(Level)
                     from TABLE_NAME
                 group by Code,
                          Area,
                          Department)
```

Comment: Thanks you very much for taking the time to assist. I tried the solution for juergen d above and that worked. But once again thank you for taking the time to help.

Comment: FYI this solution is for MySQL or similar

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like

```
SELECT Code, Area, Department, Level, Name
FROM (
  SELECT Code, Area, Department, Level, Name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Code, Area, Department, Name ORDER BY Level) __RN
  FROM TABLE_NAME) subQuery
WHERE __RN = 1
```

Without knowing more about the schema of the table, it's not easy to say what would be the best way of joining from a grouped version of your data to the table. Using ROW_NUMBER() is likely to be far more efficient, but you might be able to reduce the elements in your partition depending on what is actually the unique key in your table.

Comment: Thanks you very much for taking the time to assist. I tried the solution for juergen d above and that worked. But once again thank you for taking the time to help.

Answer (score 0):

```
select   
   s.*   
from table s,  
   (select   
      code, area, department, min(level) m  
    from 
      table  
    group by 
      code,area,department  
) min_v  
where 
   s.code = min_v.code  
   and s.area= min_v.area  
   and s.department = min_v.department  
   and s.level = min_v.m  
;
```

Comment: Thanks you very much for taking the time to assist. I tried the solution for juergen d above and that worked. But once again thank you for taking the time to help.